# How can these two pieces of code produce different behaviours?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

I'm working on a simple implementation of a Deep Neural Network, but found that this two different python class init methods are producing different behaviors and I can't explain why.

Full class with 1st init method version:

```
import numpy as np

Class DeepNeuralNetwork():
   def __init__(self, nx, layers):
        """
        @nx is the number of input features
        @layers is a list representing the number
        of nodes in each layer of the network
        """
        self.__L = len(layers)
        self.__cache = {}
        self.__weights = {}
        layers.insert(0, nx)
**
        for i in range(1, len(layers)):
            self.__weights["W{}".format(i)] = np.random.randn(
                layers[i], layers[i - 1]) * np.sqrt(2 / layers[i - 1])
            self.__weights["b{}".format(i)] = np.zeros((layers[i], 1))**


    def forward_prop(self, X):
        """ Calculates forward propagation """
        self.__cache["A0"] = X
        for i in range(1, self.L + 1):
            weight = self.weights["W{}".format(i)]
            prev_activation = self.cache["A{}".format(i-1)]
            bias = self.weights["b{}".format(i)]
            zI = np.matmul(weight, prev_activation) + bias
            self.__cache["A{}".format(i)] = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-zI))

        return self.cache["A{}".format(self.L)], self.cache
```

Second init version:

```
        for i in range(1, self.L + 1):
            if i == 1:
                self.__weights["W" + str(i)] = \
                    np.random.randn(layers[i - 1], nx) * np.sqrt(2 / nx)
            else:
                self.__weights["W" + str(i)] = \
                    np.random.randn(layers[i - 1], layers[i - 2]) * \
                    np.sqrt(2 / layers[i - 2])
            self.__weights["b" + str(i)] = np.zeros((layers[i - 1], 1))
```

As you can see the first and second init methods are almost identical except that in the first version I first added the nx integer to the layers list before the for loop and in the second one they treat the first iteration specifically to use nx, but overall they should work the exact same way, right?

The other thing is that if I create two objects using the two versions, all of the shapes of the weights and biases arrays are correct, but when trying to execute the forward_prop method I get an error because of the shapes.

When using the second init version everything worked out fine but the first one doesn't work. For example with this test file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
Deep = __import__('18-deep_neural_network').DeepNeuralNetwork

np.random.seed(18)
nx, m = np.random.randint(100, 1000, 2).tolist()
l = np.random.randint(3, 10)
sizes = np.random.randint(5, 20, l - 1).tolist()
sizes.append(1)
print(nx, sizes, m)
d = Deep(nx, sizes)
for i in range(l):
    d._DeepNeuralNetwork__weights['b' + str(i + 1)] = np.ones((sizes[i], 1))
X = np.random.randn(nx, m)
A, cache = d.forward_prop(X)
print(A)
for k, v in sorted(cache.items()):
    print(k, v)
```

I get the following error:

```
398 [10, 19, 1] 375
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "18test.py", line 17, in <module>
    A, cache = d.forward_prop(X)
  File "/home/supervised_learning/classification/18-deep_neural_network.py", line 64, in forward_prop
    zI = np.matmul(weight, prev_activation) + bias
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10,375) (398,1)
```

Comment: Just for clarification in the second init method also has this lines before the for loop:
```
        self.__L = len(layers)
        self.__cache = {}
        self.__weights = {}
```
But in that version we don't add "nx" at index 0 of "layers"

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to already work.

```py
class DeepNeuralNetwork:
    def __init__(self, nx, layers, init='first'):
        """
        @nx is the number of input features
        @layers is a list representing the number
        of nodes in each layer of the network
        """
        self.L = len(layers)
        self.cache = {}
        self.weights = {}
        layers.insert(0, nx)

        if init == 'first':
            self.first_init(layers)
        else:
            self.second_init(layers)

    def first_init(self, layers: list):
        print('first_init()')
        for i in range(1, len(layers)):
            self.weights["W{}".format(i)] = np.random.randn(
                layers[i], layers[i - 1]) * np.sqrt(2 / layers[i - 1])
            self.weights["b{}".format(i)] = np.zeros((layers[i], 1))

    def second_init(self, layers: list):
        print('second_init()')
        nx = layers[0]

        for i in range(1, self.L + 1):
            if i == 1:
                self.weights["W" + str(i)] = \
                    np.random.randn(layers[i - 1], nx) * np.sqrt(2 / nx)
            else:
                self.weights["W" + str(i)] = \
                    np.random.randn(layers[i - 1], layers[i - 2]) * \
                    np.sqrt(2 / layers[i - 2])

            self.weights["b" + str(i)] = np.zeros((layers[i - 1], 1))

    def forward_prop(self, X):
        """ Calculates forward propagation """
        self.cache["A0"] = X
        for i in range(1, self.L + 1):
            weight = self.weights["W{}".format(i)]
            prev_activation = self.cache["A{}".format(i - 1)]

            bias = self.weights["b{}".format(i)]
            zI = np.matmul(weight, prev_activation) + bias

            self.cache["A{}".format(i)] = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-zI))

        return self.cache["A{}".format(self.L)], self.cache
```

When building the network call it as follows:

```py
d = DeepNeuralNetwork(nx, sizes, init='first')
```

or

```py
d = DeepNeuralNetwork(nx, sizes, init='second')
```

Note: I've just formatted it a bit and removed the `__` before the fields (it gave my an error), but did NO changes to your logic.